# Maven enunciate error: "String index out of range: 0"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, enunciate, tinkerpop

When I build my Maven project or generate my eclipse configuration using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.28:docs (default) on project appserver-server: Problem assembling the enunciate app. String index out of range: 0 -> [Help 1]
```

I have isolated the issue to a single dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
    <artifactId>blueprints-neo4j-graph</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I need this dependency, so getting rid of it isn't an option but why is this causing an error in enunciate to appear? Is there any way to fix this?

**Edit:** after some further testing, the root of the problem may be from this dependency of a dependency of a dependency of a dependency of the previous dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Full error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.28:docs (default) on project appserver-server: Problem assembling the enunciate app. String index out of range: 0 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.28:docs (default) on project appserver-server: Problem assembling the enunciate app.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:364)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Problem assembling the enunciate app.
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.DocsMojo.execute(DocsMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.ImportedClassesClasspathHandler.handleResource(ImportedClassesClasspathHandler.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.scanClasspath(Enunciate.java:462)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.doGenerate(Enunciate.java:355)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.ConfigMojo$MavenSpecificEnunciate.doGenerate(ConfigMojo.java:670)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.step(Enunciate.java:1799)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.stepTo(Enunciate.java:1831)
    at org.codehaus.enunciate.DocsMojo.execute(DocsMojo.java:96)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Note that this approach is deprecated in favor of m2eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. That was reported and fixed [here](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/issues/42).